# In Docker, can I use the JSON format for entrypoint from the command line?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to override the entrypoint of a docker image.

I know I can do this using the `--entrypoint` option of `docker run`, but I cannot figure out how to format the argument. I know how to write the entrypoint in the JSON format. It is:

```
["/usr/bin/python2.7", "startup.py"]
```

I really need this form because I need the CMD arguments to be passed through to the entrypoint, which as I understand happens only in this exec format (and not the shell format).

I have tried:

```
docker run --entrypoint "/usr/bin/python2.7 startup.py"
```

but that does not work.

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: It looks like it is impossible in Docker CLI, but you can do that through docker-compose.

Answer (score 0):

The command-line parameters for the entrypoint need to come after the image name

ex:
`docker run --entrypoint /usr/bin/python2.7 image startup.py`

Comment: Doesn't this make "startup.py" a "CMD" and will this not therefore override the CMD of the Dockerfile?

Comment: The usage is explained here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime